# JavaScript Constructor Argument

Tags: javascript, html, oop, constructor

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/) on how to make a simple game in HTML5, and I came across an interesting use of a parameter that i cannot understand...  here the author creates a constructor called Bullet with a single parameter I, but look how he uses I.   What is going on here?  I don't understand:

```
function Bullet(I) {
    I.active = true;

    I.xVelocity = 0;
    I.yVelocity = -I.speed;
    I.width = 3;
    I.height = 3;
    I.color = "#000";

    I.inBounds = function() {
        return I.x >= 0 && I.x <= CANVAS_WIDTH &&
        I.y >= 0 && I.y <= CANVAS_HEIGHT;
    };

    I.draw = function() {
        canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
        canvas.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };

    I.update = function() {
        I.x += I.xVelocity;
        I.y += I.yVelocity;
    };

    return I;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

according to that tutorial, `Bullet` isn't a constructor, just a function that takes an existing object, augments (appends) properties and returns the object back. It then puts the returned object (with the additional properties) to the `playerBullets` array.

```
playerBullets.push(Bullet({  //the Bullet call, passing an object
    speed: 5,
    x: bulletPosition.x,
    y: bulletPosition.y
}))
```

the returned object from `Bullet` will look like:

```
{
    //the passed object
    x:...,
    y:...,
    speed:...,
    //the added properties
    xVelocity:...,
    yVelocity:...,
    ...,
    update:function(){...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but right before the block of code I posted in teh question it says the following: "Next, we need a constructor to create bullet instances."  So how is it not a constructor?

Comment: @ErickMaynard if it created "instances", then it should have been using the `new` keyword. creating instances out of constructor functions call it like `var test = new ConstructorName()`. This returns an object afterwards and stores it to `test`. But in that tutorial, it's not. It just takes in an existing object, augments it and returns it. There were no instances created.

Comment: I guess Im still confused.  It eventually draws a "bullet" to the screen in the canvas.  How is it doing this if it never creates instances of the bullet?

Comment: @ErickMaynard instances created from constructors use `new`. this one didn't. the object came from the parameter of the call to `Bullet`. There were no instances created *from the constructor*, but we did create an instance of `Object` using the object literal that was passed to it. So it's not the constructor that created the instance.